# Prefer destructuring es-lint error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, destructuring

I have this function:

```
const calculateTotal = (items) => {
  return items.reduce((totalPrice, basketItem) => {
    const price = basketItem.product.price;
    const quantity = basketItem.quantity;
    const total = price * quantity;
    return totalPrice + total;
  }, 0);
};
```

How do I fix this with ES6+ destructuring?

I know I need something like (on line 4):

`const { basketItem: quantity } = quantity;`

but I can't get line 3 working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the what you attempted doing, you could do this to get `price` from `product` and `quantity` from `basketItem` without having to declare variables on two separate lines.

```
const calculateTotal = (items) => {
  return items.reduce((totalPrice, basketItem) => {
    const { product: { price }, quantity } = basketItem;

    const total = price * quantity;
    return totalPrice + total;
  }, 0);
};
```

Answer (score 6):

```
const quantity=basketItem.quantity;
```

below this destructuring method :

```
const {quantity}=basketItem;
```

Comment: this answer was v helpful!